# UIWebView display content when shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In **BViewController** there is a *webView* that can load html from a local file in method `viewDidLoad`,  when push **BViewController** from **AViewController**(a NavigationViewController), the *webView* displays a white page for a while then displays the html content.

Is there any way to load html directly with white page?

Answer (score 1):

First load your html to your webView and then add it as subView.

Comment: I did as you said, but there is still a white page first.

Comment: its white color is because of your view background, make your view background what ever you want...and clear color of webview